# Cannot connect to remote repo using svn or tortoisesvn

Tags: macos, svn, tortoisesvn, parallels

I'm on a MacBook running 10.7 with little snitch with parallels 7 and a windows 7 ultimate VM with a bridged network connection and eset smart security 4, windows firewall is disabled.

I'm trying to checkout an existing repository that I have verified the connection to in firefox as well as an svn client (phpstorm) on the host, as well as on tortoisesvn on another VMware based virtual machine.

Below is the problem I encounter when I try:
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin>svn info http://user@www.domain.com/svn
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://user@www.domain.com/svn'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://user@www.domain.com/svn': Could not resolve
 hostname `http://user@www.domain.com/svn': The requested name is valid, but no
data of the requested type was found.
 (http://www.domain.com)

Using the phpstorm client is not an option because it doesn't support svn version 1.7 yet

Comment: Have you tried to do an nslookup servername ? it looks you have a network problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise i was able to ping it, and I was also able to run svn commands from the mac host. I think its a problem with running SVN through parallels

Comment: Have you configured the NAT in parallels ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm running bridged. My guest is connected directly to the router.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use the `svn://` protocol not the `http://` protocol to access subversion repositories: perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: My svn server is set to listen through 80 on http. So svn:// wouldn't work. Also, it works through http:// fine when I access it on my mac host and through my guest vmware vm on my workstation (i'm trying to make it work on my mac on a parallels vm)

Answer (score 1):

Could not resolve hostname - you can't resolve hostname of guest on host OS

Comment: My repository is hosted on a vps, not on my guest. I'm trying to checkout a repository on my guest machine from the VPS. I think the problem is svn not being able to work from the guest machine. My networking is bridged, so the guest has its own IP on the network.

Comment: @ton.yeung - well, your guest could not resolve hostname of repository. If you can 1. resolve any host from gust by any tool (nslookup) 2. nslookup repository-name and **only** 3. svn can't resolve - we'll try to solve this real problem instead of not-a-problem-here, but in another place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Shared network? I found it to be the best option in my MacBook & Parallels. I can also access our VPN network from Windows 7 without a problem. We use PPTP and I have configured PPTP to direct all traffic via it, when it is open. Our SVN is only available via PPTP/HTTPS.